# Reoccuring DNS Lookup Failed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

For some reason, seemingly at random, any attempts to resolve a domain fail in my network. Any existing connections will continue to work, since their domain names have already been resolved, but if I try to open any new connections by domain, it fails. Restarting the router temporarily fixes the problem, as does switching the router to different DNS servers (I've been bouncing back and fourth between Google Public DNS and my ISP's), and setting the DNS in my computer's network settings seems to have given me a semi-permanent workaround (though I won't really know if it worked unless it stops working). 
I may have found a workaround, but why did this keep happening, and is there any way to completely fix it?

Comment: It sounds like the DNS server on your router is flakey and you probably can't do much about that aside from looking into what firmware patches or replacements might be available. You should be able to put your ISP or Google DNS server IPs in the DHCP settings on your router, so you don't have to set them manually on your computers.

Comment: I have been putting the DNS settings on my router's DHCP settings, and previously I was using that to bounce back and fourth between my ISP's DNS servers and Google's DNS servers. Setting it on my computer's network settings is what seemed to have given me a workaround. 
Thank you though; I'll look into firmware patches.

Comment: You'll get nothing but conjecture without a concrete example.  What DNS name `specifically` is failing?

Comment: All of them fail to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing some failure issues with Google DNS.. some names aren't getting resolved in the US region. While its working perfectly fine in India region

Comment: Why would my ISP's DNS be affected along with every domain I've tried when the Google DNS server stop working for me?